# Blitline "burst_pdf" jobs fail and no postback is received

Tags: blitline

We're using "**burst_pdf**" conversions and they have been working fine until recently.

However, since two days back all jobs fail, and looking at the Blitline dashboard we see that queued jobs fail with the following error:

**"Image processing failed. comparison of String with 1.2 failed"**

Also, the error messages say:

"**Original Photo Metadata -> null**", but I'm not sure if that's related to what's causing the errors.

The original submissiosn to the queue work just fine and we get a valid response back from Blitline. However, we no longer get any postbacks, even though I was expecting one even if a job fails (to notify us that an error occured)?

Have reached out to Blitline for help but haven't heard anything back yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to a Blitline bug which has since been fixed.